# htaccess and my script creating a loop

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, loops, redirect

i made a script in php which checks all the incoming traffic for certain parameters and then decides if it has to redirect the traffic to the offer page or my normal site.

in htaccess i made all the traffic to pass through to the script.

now the issue is, the traffic which redirects to CPA offer is all good and working as required but the one that has not passed the tests and should be sent to normal site is stuck in a loop.

the script send the traffic to normal site but htaccess again sends it to the script and this loop keeps on going.

this is the rule i have added in htaccess.

```
RewriteRule (.*)$ xxx/script.php?a=$1
```

please help me get rid of this loop. i am not good with htaccess coding but i think if following logic can e coded, it should stop the loop.

rewrite condition (the condition should check if the referral of the traffic is NOT site itself then it sends the traffic to the script.if it is then it goes in normal site.)

Answer (score 0):

A simple test:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !xxx/script\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /xxx/script.php?a=$1 [L,R]
```

?

#### Edit:

Added [R] flag, only script.php is visible in the browser's address bar.

Comment: will this code insures that the user that lands on normal site will be able to navigate within it. one change that i tried just let the user to land on 1 requested page and then again that user was stuck into a loop.

Comment: With this user can only access one single URL.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid this check for requests that are for a file or directory like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# request is no for a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# request is no for a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
# forward to a script for checks
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /xxx/script.php?a=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: will this code insures that the user that lands on normal site will be able to navigate within it. one change that i tried just let the user to land on 1 requested page and then again that user was stuck into a loop.

Comment: I didn't what you mean by `one change that i tried just let the user to land on 1 requested page`

Comment: i meant, will this change allow the user who is sent to the site, navigate all pages or it will just allow him 1 URL which he originally requested.

Comment: This is internal rewrite so an outside visitor on your website wouldn't even know that this rewrite has happened behind the scenes.